# Rename txt file based on variable (multiple) contents

Tags: batch-file

Here is what I am trying to achieve:
I have multiple text files in a single folder with arbitrary names. I would like to read the text files and from the 2nd line of contents extract two phrases to then be used to rename the file.
Here is the typical structure of the files in question (first 3 lines):

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Company Pty Ltd                EXAMPLE SUMMARY LIST           Model : MODEL_1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I would like to take the model name and list title to create (for this example) the file "MODEL_1 EXAMPLE SUMMARY LIST.txt"
The issue I have is that the "title" varies in length and position on the line (but always between the 18th and 41st character).
I am using some code I found to parse the spaces before and after the title combined with code to rename the file, but I dont know how to go about adding the "model" part or how to make it recursive (as it only processes one file each time the batch file is run).

Here is the code I have so far:

```
@echo off&setlocal
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /a-d/b *.txt') do (
   set "nname="
   set "fname=%%~i"
   for /f "usebackqskip=1delims=" %%f in ("%%~i") do if not defined nname set "nname=%%f"
   setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
   set "nname=!nname:~18,41!"
   set "nname=!nname!"

:: **** Begin space compression code ****
:loop
if defined nname (
  set "new=!nname:  = !"
  if "!new!" neq "!nname!" (
    set "nname=!new!"
    goto :loop
  )
)
if defined nname if "!nname:~0,1!" equ " " set "nname=!nname:~1!"
if defined nname if "!nname:~-1!" equ " " set "nname=!nname:~0,-1!"
:: **** End space compression code **** 
   rename "!fname!" "!nname!.txt"
endlocal
)
```

Any suggestiions on how I could get the outcome I require would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
PUSHD "%sourcedir%"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('dir /b /a-d q*.txt') DO (
 SET "line="
 FOR /f "usebackq skip=1 tokens=1* delims=:" %%b IN ("%%a") DO IF NOT DEFINED line (
  SET "line=%%b"&SET "model=%%c"
  CALL :process
  ECHO(REN "%%a" "!model:~1! !line!.txt"
  ECHO(used "%%b"
 )
)
popd
GOTO :EOF

:process
SET "line=%line:~17,-6%"
:stripL
IF "%line:~0,1%"==" " SET "line=%line:~1%"&GOTO stripL
:stripR
IF "%line:~-1%"==" " SET "line=%line:~0,-1%"&GOTO stripR

GOTO :eof
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

I used a file named `q28192545.txt` containing your data for my testing and set a filemask of `q*.txt` to ensure only `q*.txt` files were used for testing.

First, switch temporarily to the directory in question.

Then obtain a directory of the filenames-only and assign each in turn to `%%a`

Use the variable `line` as a flag and to contain the processed name. First clear `line` so it's undefined, then read the file `%%a`, skipping the first line and using `:` as a delimiter, assign the second line up to the colon in `%%b` and the part past the colon into `%%c`; assign these to nor mal environment variables `line` and `model`.

Since `line` is now defined, the process will not take place for the remainder of the lines in `%%a`.

Process `line` - first by removing the first 17 characters and the last 6 characters (Not really sure whether the company name will ever occupy more than 17 characters - not specified). The last 6 characters were `model` (before the colon)

Now remove the spaces on the left, and then a step to the right, and the title should be neatly trimmed.

Return from the process and the rename can take place to the string in `model` (except the first character, which will be a space) + a space _ the remainder of `line` + `.txt`

Final, just for documentation, show the line which gave rise to the rename.

The required REN commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(REN` to `REN` to actually rename the files.

Comment: Magoo, Works perfectly. Thank you for the thorough expalnation of how it was achieved. The comapny name never changes, so all good. The file will always be run from within the folder containing the files to be renamed, as such I have removed the sourcedir lines.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**: *Small bug fixed*

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem For all text files in folder
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('dir /A-D /B *.txt') do (
   rem Get the 2nd line and divide it at the colon
   set "line="
   for /F "usebackq skip=1 tokens=1,2 delims=:" %%b in ("%%a") do (
      if not defined line (
         set "line=%%b"
         set "model=%%c"
      )
   )
   rem Join the model plus all the words in line from char 18 take 41
   set "nname="
   for %%b in (!model! !line:~18^,41!) do set "nname=!nname! %%b"
   rem Rename the file (remove additional space at beginning of nname)
   ren "%%a" "!nname:~1!.txt"
)
```

This method join the words placed in a FOR command with a space between they. In your example, the FOR would be something like this:

```
for %%b in (  MODEL_1              EXAMPLE SUMMARY LIST       ) do set "nname=!nname! %%b"
```

... that would produce this:

```
set "nname= MODEL_1 EXAMPLE SUMMARY LIST"
```

... with one additional space at beginning. Of course, this method will not work if the words may contain any wild-card or special character...

Comment: Hi Aacini, thanks for you answer. I understand your methodology from your explanation, but I get  "A duplicate file name exists, or the file cannot be found" error when it is run.

Comment: This indicate that there are two files with the same model and title... You may duplicate the `ren` line and add an `ECHO` this way: `ECHO ren "%%a" "!nname:~1!.txt"` so you may review the names used and detect which file have the duplicated new name.

Comment: Hi Aacinin, the other two scripts run without error and achieve the requested goal, so I dont see how there can be any duplicates. They were all run on the same set of files. The model name is the same, but all titles are different (but may contain duplicate individual words with them eg "Site Summary" and "Bolt Summary" - maybe thats an issue?

Comment: Adding echo produces this output:  ren "TEST.txt" "RAIL line:~18 41.txt"  "Rail" being the model name.

Comment: Ops! There was a subtle bug **`:/`** (a caret was missing before the comma at this part: `!line:~18^,41!`). Please, copy the program again, test it and look at _the time it tooks to run_...

Comment: Works perfectly with the correction made - thanks!. I wont be processing large numbers of files at a time, but rather a small number processed often - so speed is not really a factor. Thanks again for your help Aacini.

Answer (score 0):

Biggest problem I see is that you've got a label (`:loop`) and `goto` within your outer `for /f` loop.  Don't do that.  As soon as `goto` is reached, the outer loop will break.  If you ever need to use a `goto` without breaking out of a loop, move the relevant code block outside the loop and use `call`.  See [this batch function tutorial](http://www.dostips.com/DtTutoFunctions.php) for useful ways to do this.

Scraping the model and summary would be much easier using a regexp split.  There's not really a pure batch way to do that (unless you've got `sed` or `grep` or similar in your path), but you can invoke JScript or VB Script or PowerShell pretty easily.  I personally prefer JScript, as it's very easy to invoke [as a hybrid script](https://gist.github.com/davidruhmann/5199433), and because it has the already familiar syntax of IE7 JavaScript (just with the "window" and "document" objects replaced with Windows-specific methods and objects).

So anyway, if your example above is representative of all the files you wish to scrape, then scraping the model part can be handled by splitting on 2 or more whitespace characters.  JScript makes this easy.  Just split on `/\s\s+/`.

And after you get rid of that `:loop` and `goto` within your outer `for` loop, you can make your script search for `*.txt` recursively with a `for /r` loop.

```js
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then

@echo off
setlocal

for /r %%I in (*.txt) do (
    pushd "%%~dpI"
    call :scrape company summary model "%%~fI"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    >NUL 2>&1 ren "%%~nxI" "!model! !summary!%%~xI" && (
        echo %%~nxI -^> !model! !summary!%%~xI
    ) || (
        echo %%~nxI: rename conflict.
    )
    endlocal
    popd
)

goto :EOF

:scrape <var1> <var2> <var3> <txtfile>
setlocal
for /f "delims=" %%I in ('cscript /nologo /e:JScript "%~f0" "%~4"') do set "%%I"
endlocal & set "%~1=%v1%" & set "%~2=%v2%" & set "%~3=%v3%"
goto :EOF

@end

// JScript portion

String.prototype.trim = function() { return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/,''); }

var fso = WSH.CreateObject('scripting.filesystemobject'),
    file = fso.OpenTextFile(WSH.Arguments(0), 1),
    line = file.SkipLine() || file.ReadLine(),
    params = line.split(/\s\s+/),
    v1 = params[0].trim(),
    v2 = params[1].trim(),
    v3 = params[2].split(':')[1].trim();

file.Close();
WSH.Echo('v1=' + v1 + '\nv2=' + v2 + '\nv3=' + v3);
```

Comment: Thanks very much Rojo, the script does exactly as required. I see now why the recursive function didn't work with the goto added. Thanks for taking the time to explain it in detail - very helpful